# Instruction at Address 0x000000 crashes

Tags: segmentation-fault, armv7

Need help: a dynamically linked program crashes at address 0x0, IMHO the first executable instruction of the code. The program is cross-compiled using gcc:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/cross/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/7.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/opt/cross --enable-bootstrap=no --build=x86_64-suse-linux --target=arm-linux-gnueabi --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-float=soft --disable-libmudflap --disable-multilib --with-cpu=arm7tdmi --with-float=soft
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.2.0 (GCC)
```

Executing the program under gdb results in an immediate segmentation fault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

0x00000000 in ?? ()

(gdb) info registers    
r0             0x0      0
r1             0xbefff767       3204446055    
r2             0x0      0    
r3             0x2a017000       704737280    
r4             0x0      0    
r5             0x0      0    
r6             0x0      0    
r7             0x0      0    
r8             0x0      0    
r9             0x0      0    
r10            0x0      0    
r11            0x0      0    
r12            0x0      0    
sp             0xbefff640       0xbefff640
lr             0x0      0    
pc             0x0      0x0    
cpsr           0x60000010       1610612752
```

The executable *file*: `ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped`

The libraries reside in the common path (/lib/).

The target system *uname -a*: `Linux nanoPi 3.4.39-h3 #12 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 23 15:51:07 CST 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux`

*compile options*: `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_SOURCE=1 (... some source files ...) -O0 -g3 -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/options.d" -MT"src/options.o" -o "src/options.o" "../src/options.c"`

Linking statically, the program works as intended.

I'm stuck on this issue for some hours now, running out of ideas what to try or where to look further. Google search mostly returns references to dereferencing Null Pointers, but I think that this is a different case.

Any hint appreciated.

Comment: Are you linking into a different Endian format perhaps?  Or struct data alignment?

Comment: No ...-endian options involved. No linker options aside from -shared, no optimization (O0), with debugging (-g3). Endianess is the same as in the static case.

Comment: are you trying to run some baremetal code and boot from it or run a program on linux?  Please show disassembly if beginning of program.

Comment: You should have run `ldd` on the binary to see what was loading.  There are also gdb options to debug startup (before `main()`; usually the symbol `_start`) as you may have some issue here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you comments. At last I was able to get it running, seemed to stem from a difference in the shared libs btw. build host's toolchain and target.